# Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client when return the response in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

when i send a request to this function it show me this error :

```
    events.js:292
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client
    at ServerResponse.setHeader (_http_outgoing.js:533:11)
    at ServerResponse.header (F:\Projects\Nodejs\SalesSignal\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:771:10)
    at ServerResponse.send (F:\Projects\Nodejs\SalesSignal\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:170:12)
    at ServerResponse.json (F:\Projects\Nodejs\SalesSignal\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:267:15)
    at ServerResponse.send (F:\Projects\Nodejs\SalesSignal\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:158:21)
    at ManagerController.Ok (F:\Projects\Nodejs\SalesSignal\src\http\controller\BaseController.js:18:28)
    at F:\Projects\Nodejs\SalesSignal\src\http\controller\ManagerController.js:121:25
```

my function is this and this function fir update record :

```
      async DeleteManager(req, res, next) {
    let result = await this.ValidationAction(req, res);
    if (result[0]) {
      const user = Manager.findByIdAndUpdate(
        req.params.id,
        { $set: { isDelete: true } },
        { useFindAndModify: false },
        (error, user) => {
          if (error) {
            next(error);
          } else if (!user) {
            return  res.status(200).send({
              message: "رکورد مورد نظر یافت نشد",
              statusCode: 200,
              success: false,
            });
          } else {
            return res.status(200).send({
              message: "عملیات با موفقیت انجام شد",
              statusCode: 200,
              success: true,
            });
          }
        }
      );
    }
    return this.BadRerquest(res, result[1]);
  }
```

when i send a request to this functin it update record in database but it show me this error .

**whats the problem ? how can i solve thus problem ?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely your app tries to send multiple responses to the single request.
This may happen because the app seems to always send `BadRequest` even if there is `result[0]`. Try to change the control flow from:

```
if (result[0]) {
  // ...
}
return this.BadRerquest(res, result[1]);
```

to

```
if (result[0]) {
  // ...
} else {
  return this.BadRerquest(res, result[1]);
}
```